# Running Node.js Server using User Level Root

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, localhost, server

Basic question but not sure where to turn to start figuring this out.

I've setup a very simple node server on port 3000 that just responds with an index.html file. When I call `http://localhost:3000` in the browser, I get the proper page served up with dependencies. I don't want to authenticate every time though so I'd like to run it from the user-level.

I tried typing `http://localhost~myusername:3000` in the browser but I keep getting:

`The requested URL /~myusername:3000 was not found on this server.`

(I have setup user-level root to be accessed through `~/Sites` and have gotten access to files through here, even php, it's just when I start using a node server this problem occurs.)

How can I get node.js to respond to user-level requests? And it serve up the proper `index.html` from the relative path of the user-level root instead of `/library/WebServer/Documents`?

**Update**
Code of server.js:

var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

```
function send404(response) {
    response.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    response.write('Error 404: Resource not found.');
    response.end();
}

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.method == 'GET' && req.url == '/') {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/html' });
        fs.createReadStream('./index.html').pipe(res);
    }
    else {
        send404(res);
    }
}).listen(3000);
console.log('server running on port 3000');
```

Comment: as a non-root user visiting `http://localhost:3000`  doesn't work for you?

Comment: I get this: `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
ReloadHide details
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.`

Comment: I'm thinking maybe your user doesn't have permission to serve the index.html file. Does it have the right permissions? And if it does, can you post some node server code?

Comment: Also, remember that the user should have permission to execute ('x') every directory leading up to the directory in which the index.html file is, so it's not enough to set the permissions just on that folder.

Comment: Just updated with the code.

Comment: Code looks fine. If you are getting the same `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` on visiting other pages then I guess it's not a file permission issue either. Try putting a `console.log` inside the request handler to make sure node is receiving the request at all.

Comment: I'm now getting this: `server running on port 3000
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: ENOENT, open './index.html'
    at Error (native)` whenever I run `node server.js`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77576/discussion-between-sidd-and-inthenameofmusik).